How do I change default MinGW g++ from C++17 to C++20
I'm a beginner at C++ and I uses MinGW for VS Code, recently I wanted to move from C++17 to C++20 but I don't know how yet
So far the things I found are either too complex or doesn't work for me. There's an option to manually specify which C++ version will be used every time I want to execute my code but that's too tedious and repetitive

Then is there any way to change the default C++ version directly instead?

How are you compiling at the moment: makefile, command-line, IDE etc ?

I'm using VS Code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm using VS Code That didn't answer the question. There are several different building methods when using VSCode. The default method you create a tasks.json and set the standard in the args: according to the documentation:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw You could also use a Makefile and the Makefile tools extension or a CMakeLists.txt and the CMake Tools extension. Or you could use code-runner which is very much not recommended for c++ based code.

@drescherjm I found a post about specifying a C++ version for code execution in VS Code. Modifying my task.json to specify -std=c++20 every time a .cpp file is executed solved my problem.

Yes that is one solution. You may also want to change the standard in the cppStandard c_cpp_properties.json so intellisense knows. This doesn't affect building but the editor squiggles.

Ah alright, thanks for helping! @drescherjm

You can create a Makefile where you can set flags for the specific version. I am guessing since you are new you won't be needing more than one source file. So writing your own Makefile won't be difficult.

May I ask how can I create a Makefile (sorry I'm almost entirely fresh to C++)?

VSCode is not very beginner friendly at all. Its required that you understand a little about your compilers command line arguments, or know how to create a Makefile or CMakeLists.txt once your code has exceeded 1 source file or needs some external library or needs any type of non default setting.
